# window.close() in success function

Tags: jquery

I have a typical ajax post type with a success function.
I have tried in many different ways to close window on success. 
But only after message is revealed and can be read.

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"file.php",
data:info,
success:function(){
$('#load').empty();
$('#information').html('Thank you!');
\\setTimeout('window.close()',2000); \\
}
});
return false;
```

**Page is opened with "window.open()"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
setTimeout(function(){window.close();},2000);
```

you can also get reference to window:

```
var wind = window.open();//then
setTimeout(function(){wind.close();},2000);
```